# how to convert date which i got from firebase server as am getting error Date

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I want to convert Long value to String or Date in this format. I got this value in Long format: `2343805819061` which I got from Firebase timestamp. When ever I am trying I got the error that cant use Date into string:

```
    //constrictor
    public Wall_post( Date time_stamp) {

        this.time_stamp = time_stamp;

    }
    public Date getTime_stamp() {
        return time_stamp;
    }

    public void setTime_stamp(Date time_stamp) {
        this.time_stamp = time_stamp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now use this code & let me know if it solves your problem

```
 //date converter
        String dateInToString = DateFormat.format("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Date(time)).toString();
```

you can find more date formate details from bellow link
[SampleDateFormate || Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)

Answer (score 0):

using

```
   public static Date millisToDate(long millis) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

Comment: i do that but getting error when ever i want to pass the return value

Comment: can you provide the log of this error ? you can find it in logcat

Comment: i fixed it thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To get the timestamp in a String format, please use the following method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "time";
    }
}
```

If you want only the date, then just use the following method:

```
public static String getDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```